# Bind keys over SSH to switch tmux tabs

Tags: ssh, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, putty, tmux

I typically have 4 or 5 tmux "tabs" (aka tmux windows) open.
They are created by pressing Control+B, C

In many applications you can Control+Tab to switch between tabs (or internal windows, or whatever). You can see this in Firefox, Chrome, Sublime Text, Dolphin, etc etc etc.

How can I tell tmux to do this too?

I already tried the following in ~/.tmux.conf:

bind-key C-Tab next-window
bind-key C-S-Tab previous-window

But it doesn't work.

I am using: Windows 8.1, Putty 0.63 and tmux 1.8

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to send the prefix ('C-b') before tmux will listen for your key binding.

From the [man page for tmux(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/tmux.1.html)

> **KEY BINDINGS**
>   tmux may be controlled from an attached client by using a key combination of a prefix key, 'C-b' (Ctrl->b) by default, followed by a command key.

So Ctrl-Tab on it's own will not work. You need to type the prefix first.

It is possible to bind keys that don't require the prefix by using passing the -n argument to bind-keys like so:

```
bind-keys -n C-Tab next-window
bind-keys -n C-S-Tab previous-windows
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15471269/4246437) at stackoverflow.com for a lot more details.